# What does the sequence vector mean in matplotlib.pyplot.contour?

Tags: graphing-functions, matlab, python

The `contour` from [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=contour#matplotlib.pyplot.contour) supports a vector parameter **V** which description is:

```
draw contour lines at the values specified in sequence V, which must be in increasing order.
```

The MATLAB version of `contour` also supports a vector parameter, but it does not has this **in increasing order** restriction.

I want to know what does this vector means; do they have same/different meaning on these two platform.

*More detailed information about what am I doing.*

```
u = linspace(-1, 1.5, 50)
v = linspace(-1, 1.5, 50)
z = zeros((u.size, v.size))
# a loop to fill z
contour(u, v, z, [0, 0])
```

I need to set the 4th parameter to `[0, 0]` according to my tutorial. But I got

```
Contour levels must be increasing
```

Error. If I change it to `[0, 1]`, the error is gone, but the contour does not look right.

Comment: Looks like it is a [bug](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/9047).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you create a contour plot of a flat function (constantly zero) which doesn't make sense IMHO. So you can define any ascending sequence like [-5, 0, 0.2, 1, 42], but you won't see the contour lines unless you have corresponding z values.

Comment: I chatted in the matplotlib email list, and it seems it is a bug...